# Remove subdirectories from URL on IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I currently have a website running on IIS Windows Server 2019.
The website's url is : https://mywebsite.com/Sub1/login

When i get to https://mywebsite.com i obiously dont get the connexion form.
I would like to get rid of /Sub1/login and turn into https://mywebsite.com.

I tried using URL Rewrite but i don't get the syntax. Could any please help me ? :)

Comment: 1. Try to host the web app as the default site so that you don't need any rewrite rules. 2. Or if you cannot, edit the question to show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li said, you can do this by setting the default document.

1. In IIS Manager, click the server name node, and then scroll to locate the Default Document icon.
2. Double click Default Document.
3. In the Actions pane, click Add.
4. In the Add Default Document dialog box, type the full filename of the default page.(such as login.aspx)
5. Click OK.

But the premise is that your default page needs to be placed in the root directory. This way you can directly access your default page by typing `https://mywebsite.com` in your browser.

In addition, you cannot use the Rewrite operation to remove the path part of the URL, because Rewrite does not change the address in the browser.